# Office WORD 365 VBA - Select all textboxes on a specific page

Tags: vba

.I've been try to figure out a way to select all my text boxes on a page i WORD, some of which are hidden behind other text boxes. There are about 30 text boxes per page.
These are difficult to SHIFT select manually. There are methods to select all objects on a document of course, but I can't find any way to single out a page.

By trial and error I was able to find the objects by number and I can select them using the following code

```
    Sub GetPageTextBoxes()

    Dim pageNum As Integer

    'Shape Numbers on Page 4
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array(37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45)).Select
End Sub
```

The example only selects a few of them. Objects are numbered as they are created so shape 45 and 46 can be on different pages.

I need a way to find and select all the shapes on a single page.
Sorry this is a Word document and I forgot to specify that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Selects all shapes on document.

```
Sub SelectAllShapesOnTheActiveSheet()
  ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to specify Word. Appologies

Answer (score 0):

For Word

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
```